# Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$. Prove that $f(x)$ is identically equal to zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$. Prove that $f(x)$ is identically equal to zero.

My approach: Since we have $$f(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$ $\forall x$, and since $f$ is continuous $\forall x$, therefore by Leibniz Rule we can conclude that $f$ is differentiable $\forall x$ and $f(x)=f'(x)$, $\forall x$.

Now since $f(x)=f'(x)$, and since $f$ is differentiable $\forall x$, therefore we can conclude that $f'$ is differentiable $\forall x$ and $f''(x)=f'(x)=f(x)$, $\forall x.$

Similar analysis tells that $$f^{(n)}(x)=f^{(n-1)}(x)=...=f''(x)=f'(x)=f(x)$$ $\forall x$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Also we have $$f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n-1)}(0)=...=f''(0)=f'(0)=f(0)=0.$$

Now let us assume that $\exists x=x_1>0$ such that $f(x_1)\neq 0$. Let us assume that $f(x_1)>0$.

After this I applied MVT to certain intervals and obtained that $f(x)=0$ at infinitely many points $x\in(0,x_1)$.

How to proceed after this?

Comment: Since $f(x)=f'(x)$ we know that $f(x)=C \exp(x)$ for some constant $C$ and $f(0)=0$ implies $C=0$. But there should be a more elementary approach I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(x)-f '(x)=0$ implies that $f(x)=ce^{x}$ for some constant $c$. [Proof: $(e^{-x}f(x))'=e^{-x} f'(x)-e^{-x} f(x)=0$ so $e^{-x}f(x)$ is a constant]. Now $f(0)=0$ so we must have $c=0$  and $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deduce from $f(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ that $f'=f$, what you need is the Fundamental theorem of Calculus, not the Leibniz Rule. From $f'=f$; you deduce that $f(x)=Ce^x$ for some consant $C$. And, since $f(0)=0$, $C=0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how do you conclude $f(x)=f'(x)$ ? I think  I may be missing something 

Comment: Differentiating both sides of the equality $f(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! But what is $\frac{d(\int _0^x f(t)dt)}{dt}$ ? I can't seem to evaluate this since it's a definitite integral not an indefinite one! Is $\frac{d(\int _0^xf(t)dt)}{dt}=f(x)$ ?

Comment: It's not $\frac{\mathrm d\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dt}$; it's $\frac{\mathrm d\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}$. And it is equal to $f(x)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now.